# Can I achieve a groupon / kickstarter like payment system with paypal uk

Tags: paypal

I.e. user clicks buy, I authorize their card and wait 2 weeks and see if enough users have pre ordered a given product before charging them and shipping.

I'd like the following -

- To avoid pci compliance I'd prefer to whisk users off to paypal for getting c.c. details.
- progmatically reauthorizing any preorders and capturing funds is fine after 2 weeks. But for my prototype doing this via the paypal account dashboard is fine.
- my app being notified when a user successfully preorders (ie. there card is authorized by paypal) in order to update my "preorder" counter on the site.

For my prototype I want to avoid as much coding on this so offloading as much as possible to paypal, even if it means I have to manually handle reauthorizations and payment captures is actually better in the short term.

Can paypal uk provide this functionality and if so which business solution is this? standard or pro?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with standard; However considering that you eventually would want a "tighter" integration with your back-end systems and, it might be a good idea to start with pro itself.

Comment: I looked through the docs but couldnt spot whether standard notifies your app re successful purchase. I know it has can redirect the user back to a page but does it also include info re: the status of the authorization i.e. fail or success??

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like your app to get notified (via some sort of "listener" for lack of better words) when a successful purchase happens. Correct? If so, did you check out the IPN documentation? Here's the link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/  Is that what you are looking for?